# What does this Intel jmpq instruction do?

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64

How is the address `0x600860` computed in the Intel instruction below? `0x4003b8` + `0x2004a2` = `60085a`, so I don't see how the computation is carried out.

`0x4003b8 <puts@plt>:   jmpq   *0x2004a2(%rip)        # 0x600860 <puts@got.plt>`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

On Intel, JMP, CALL, etc. are relative to the program counter of the *next* instruction.

The next instruction in your case was at `0x4003be`, and `0x4003be + 0x2004a2 == 0x600860`

Comment: Ah, so the formula is `Current address` + `Value before (%rip)` + `Current Instruction Size`. Thanks

Comment: And for those wondering about the "q" in jmpq, it just denotes the size of the operand (q stands for quad) in AT&T / GAS assembly syntax.

Comment: -> 0x100000ebb:  81 7d fc 03 00 00 00  cmpl   $0x3, -0x4(%rbp)
   0x100000ec2:  0f 85 06 00 00 00     jne    0x100000ece            
   0x100000ec8:  ff 25 12 ba de ff     jmpq   *-0x2145ee(%rip)
   0x100000ece:  48 8d 3d bb 00 00 00  leaq   0xbb(%rip), %rdi

Comment: I threw in some byte code incase someone wanted to see what a jmpq looked like (since i'm interested in FF 25 at the moment.   I'm actually interested in JMP /5)

Comment: @RouteMapper: Isnt there also a indirection involved? I guess that the jump addess is ```loaded``` from 0x600860 (?).

Answer (score 1):

It's AT&T syntax for a memory-indirect [JMP](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/JMP.html) with a RIP-relative addressing mode.

The jump address is fetched from the memory location that is specified relative to the instruction pointer:
first calculate `0x4003be + 0x2004a2 == 0x600860` then fetch the address to jump to from location `0x600860`.

Other addressing modes are possible, for example a jump-table might use
`jmpq *(%rdi, %rax, 8)` with the table base in RDI and the index in RAX.

RIP-relative addressing for static data is common, though.  In this case, it's addressing an entry in the GOT (Global Offset Table), set up by dynamic linking.